# How do you Xforward windows using ssh?

Tags: xorg, ssh, 12.04

How do you use `Xforwarding` through SSH beetween two ubuntu pc's?

Comment: ... so where have you heard this ... please add the web-link.

Comment: hey that was NOT what was asked :(

Comment: Really sorry @Rinzwind : http://askubuntu.com/q/114452/17722

Comment: and xpra is such a wonderful tool it's a shame you made me delete it :+ (lol)

Comment: @Rinzwind Please answer the above linked question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just opening a X application on a different machine is not difficult.

Connect to the machine `local` on which you want to start an application, but display it on your machine `remote`.

```
you@local$ ssh -X user@remote
(login etc)
user@remote$ nautilus
```

Performance may not be as good as you'd expected it to be. When disconnecting, type `exit`. If it hangs for some reason, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to tear down the connection.