# How do you reposition and move X windows across 2 different computers?

Tags: 11.10, xorg

I've heard of a  feature of X allowing users to move windows over different X servers over the network. How do I do this in ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [xpra](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xpra) [image: Install xpra]. The [[`xpra` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xpra)] is very well documented.

Run this command to install xpra.

```
sudo apt-get install xpra
```

The link to the FAQ on xpra: http://xpra.org/faq.html